# RPM extract jar files

Tags: jar, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I wan to create RPM packages which is used to extract only jar files:

```
Name:           pack-agent
Version:        1.0
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Linux Agent installation script
Group:          Utilities
License:        license
Source0:        pack-agent-1.0.tar.gz
BuildArch:      x86_64
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)
%description

%prep
%setup -q -n opt

%build

%install
#install -m 0755 -d $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/agent
#cp -ap agent/* $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/agent/

install -m 0755 -d %{buildroot}/opt
#cp -a * %{buildroot}/agent
cp -a * %{buildroot}/opt

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
/opt
%defattr(-,root,root,-)

%doc
%changelog
```

It turns out that after RPM install some files are corrupted because there is a spacial way to extract files from jar file. Maybe during build simple exatract command is used I suppose.

Is there any way to solve this? I get now this error:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle file:/opt/agent/deploy/System_Install-1.0.jar does not have a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF! Make sure, META-INF and MANIFEST.MF are the first 2 entries in your JAR!
```

Looks like the file is not properly extracted.

Comment: Your question doesn't list anything with jar files.

Comment: Could you explain how I can fix this?

Comment: That error is complaining about the jar file itself. Where does `/opt/agent/deploy/System_Install-1.0.jar` come from? How does that file relate to the spec file you included?

Comment: It's my custom jar. When I copy the jar manually after RPM install it's working fine. Looks like the RPM build process is corrupting the jar?

Comment: That's possible. RPM does try to repack jar's for compression/etc. purposes. It is possible that's breaking your jar I suppose. You could look into disabling that. Though I'd be surprised if that was actually the problem. What are the contents of that jar after RPM installs it?

Comment: Can propose some spec file solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your tarball contains jar files that should stay as they are, disable repackaging of the jar files. Add the following to the top of your spec file:

```
%define __jar_repack %{nil}
```

Answer (score 2):

Run `rpm -E '%{__os_install_post}'` and find the `brp-java-repack-jars` script (`/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars` on my CentOS 5 system) and take a look at it.

It unpacks and repacks the jars it finds.

Newer versions might let you control it a bit but in the one I have you don't have much say over things.

For the version in CentOS 5 it looks like your choices are:

- Define your own custom `__os_install_post` that doesn't call it that script
- Update the script to be smarter about handling `META-INF` and `MANIFEST.MF` files correctly.
- Delete that script from your system entirely
- Remove `zip` and/or `unzip` from your system entirely